# Tkinter button command not working with lambda exec command

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I'm a beginner in Python and coding in general and I can't get the second button to run it's command which has the string "self.terminate" to be executed here (Only 2nd button not working, 1st button works fine)

```
 c.execute("SELECT buttonText, buttonCommand FROM buttons WHERE buttonWindow=?", (frameWindow,))

 buttonValues = c.fetchall()

 for row in buttonValues:
      self.buttonRows.append(tk.Button(self, text = row[0], command = lambda self=self, buttonCommand = row[1]: exec(buttonCommand))
                             .grid(column = 0, row = self.iterationRow, padx = 10, pady = 10))
      self.iterationRow += 1
```

with terminate defined:

```
def terminate(self):
      conn.close()

      root.destroy()
```

It just does nothing. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Try `"self.terminate()"` instead.

Comment: wow, i forgot to click "apply changes" in db browser when i tried this solution before i posted this. works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your database has the value `self.terminate`, you need to append `()` when calling `exec` (ie: you need to do `exec("self.terminate()")` rather than `exec("self.terminate")`)

My advice is to not try to wrap so much code into a single line. As you are finding out, it makes it very difficult to debug. You should create a proper function for your buttons.

For example:

```
for row in buttonValues:
    button = tk.Button(self, text=row[0], command=lambda cmd=row[1]: self.do_command)
    button.grid(column=0, row=self.iterationRow, padx=10, pady=10)
    self.buttonRows.append(button)
...
def do_command(self, command):
    cmd = command + "()"
    exec(cmd)
```

This makes it far, far easier to understand and debug.

All of that being said, it seems like a highly questionable design to be storing the string representations of buttons in a database. I don't see what value you're getting out of doing that.

Comment: "All of that being said, it seems like a highly questionable design to be storing the string representations of buttons in a database. I don't see what value you're getting out of doing that" An attempt to i18n, maybe

Comment: @Gabriel: i18N a function name? I doubt it.

Comment: I am trying to do some program which has various functions for each button, so I try to store them in a database since I am more familiar with database than file making (CSV?) in another language. I am also still a high school student and deadline for this project is 2-3 weeks which is very limiting for me since I still another time-consuming task to worry about, so I'm doing this in whatever design that comes in my mind first.

Comment: @NatsuMerlin: the problem with a database is that you can only store strings that represent functions, so you're required to use tricks like `exec` which provide a security risk. This is simply not the right way to write code, and you may get low marks because of it. I realize that a security risk is probably not an issue with a school project, but you don't want to start your path to learning with flawed designs.